# Bootstrap 3 + respond.js + IE8

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap-3, respond.js

I know this is common problem, I have checked a lot of solution and nothing works. So lets begin:

Common problem: Bootstrap 3 does not work on IE8. I have added respond.js, meta tag, doctype, but without effect.

All of it is hosted on Sharepoint 2007 server, so I'm not working locally

My head:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/css/my.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="/_layouts/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
            <script src="/_layouts/js/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

    </head>
```

- I have tried to move `[if lt IE 9]` around document: after all css files, last thing before  etc. nothing helps.
- I have tried with bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.css also.
- I have also removed all stuff that is not importan
- I have changed my.css and bootstrap.css order
- Of course I have latest version of respond.js
  And it still does not have any effect.

Any help?

Comment: `Respond.js` says it doesn't work locally, you have to upload it to a web server for it to work. Are you working locally?

Comment: I am working on  Sharepoint 2007

Comment: Erp sorry can't help you then. The problems I encountered with `Respond.js` were: (a) doesn't work locally, and (b) is pretty finicky as to the make up of the `.css` files, having inline debug info breaks it, including links to `.css` files that don't exist breaks it, some invalid CSS might break it ... that's about all I can offer in terms of help, sorry.

Comment: Thanks @setek, I have found issue! one of css file link was outdated, and files does not exist.

Comment: Good good, do you want to post it as an answer to your own question or shall I post?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

One of css file link was broken.

Seems to Respond.js stops executing after file not found exception.